# Group data based on different conditions

Tags: sql

[Tables and logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEGvq.jpg)
[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFEdF.jpg)
Lets assume "column1" and "column2" are the only columns in the data table. So I'm trying to group the data based on column2. For example,  and the table is as below:

```
APL Apple
APL Apple
APL Apple
ORG Orange
ORG Apple
GVA Apple.
```

`APL` is Apple, `ORG` is Orange so they will be grouped into 'A' and 'B' respectively. and ORG Apple and GVA Apple will be grouped into "others". How do I do that? Do I need a lookup table? If yes, how do I merge the lookup table into the data table?

Comment: What is the output you want based on your sample data?

Comment: im using bigquery, so im not sure how. Actually i just want the sql code to make it work, im still working on it

Comment: I have added drawn pictures, so it will be easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, ifnull(LkpTbl.grp, 'Others') grp
FROM Table1
left outer join LkpTbl
  in table1.col1 = LkpTbl.col1
```

put your lookup table only `APL` and `ORG`  that is needed to be grouped

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a `case` expression?

```
select (case when column1 = 'APL' and column2 = 'Apple' then 'A'
             when column1 = 'ORG' and column2 = 'Orange' then 'B'
             else 'Others'
        end) as column3
from t;
```

If you want this as a lookup table, it could be something like this:

```
select t.*, coalesce(v.grp, 'Others')
from t left join
     (values ('APL', 'Apple', 'A'), ('ORG', 'Orange', 'B')
     ) v(column1, column2, grp)
     on t.column1 = v.column1 and t.column2 = v.column2;
```

Comment: say i have more than 10 rows and its everchanging, so i will probably upload the lookup table as a dataset, then lookup the data table using lookup table